# multiprocessing torch.cuda не определяет device

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing, pytorch

Из главного скрипта вызываю другой скрипт в мультипроцесе, чтобы не тормозит главное окно. Во втором скрипте есть задача определить/подтвердить существование выбранного девайса (видеокарта, процессор) для расчета. Но почему-то именно когда создается отдельный процесс, torch.cuda не определяет например существоания видеокарты под номером ид 0. А в если не создавать отдельный процесс, то все ок. Почему так и как решить эту дилему.

Использую `from multiprocessing import Process`. Через `after` не решение, так как зависает всеравно главное окно.

Момент вызова нового процесса, и момент определения девайса.

В первом скрипте

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import tkinter as tk
from two import second_script

class test(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.btn = Button(text='start', command=self.start)
        self.btn.pack()

    def start(self):
        proc = Process(target=second_script)
        proc.start()

if __name__ == "main":
    root = tk.Tk()
    test(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Во втором скрипте

```
import os
import torch

def second_script():
    os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '0'
    assert torch.cuda.is_available(), \
        f'Invalid CUDA'

#.....присутствует tkinder gui menu
#.......
```

Срабатывает ошибка и пишет инвалид.

Что не мало важно в первом скрипте весь вызов происходит из tkinter окна. И загвоздка наверно в нем, к нему привязывается девайс наверно, ведь без tkinter а просто вызов нового процесса второго скрипта, все ок.

UPD: частично разобрался, создав не отдельный процесс, а отдельный поток.

```
proc = threading.Thread(target=second_script, daemon=True)
proc.start()
```

Но возникла следующая проблема и она связа она опять с tkinter. Если во втором скрипте есть ткинтер окно, то скрипт работает ровно до его создания, на этом этапе поток тупо зависает (там окно не через `mainloop`, а просто `update`). Ну вот и как заставить дружить tkinter окна в разных потоках или процессах? А это для меня уже остарая проблема, ведь если делать весь большой проект в разных потоках, то тупо кроме главного скрипта больше нигде в скрипта окна не отрисуются.

Comment: А, ну попробуйте тогда `QProcess` вызывать. Из `tkinter` нужно его собственные потоки и процессы вызывать, иначе всё плохо обычно. Но не факт, что в данном случае поможет.

Comment: Пожалуйста, создайте, минимальный пример демонстрирующий проблему. Полный стэк-трейс ошибки. А то так полный инвалид.

Comment: @CrazyElf это метод запустит файл скрипта через пайтон заново, это может решение но не для меня, так как я проект упаковываю через pyinstaller в итоге. И второй скрипт уж никак виден не будет, а отделтно упаковывать второй скрипт, чтобы его потом открываит, тоже не вариант для меня.

Comment: @СергейКох по спецзаказу) второй скрипт ясное дело оставил где вощникает ошибка, так как весь расчет не смогу показать.

Comment: @CrazyElf у tkinter нет собственных потоков и процессов (возможно вы с pyqt путаете)

Comment: @insolor Да, я в них не силён, вестимо путаю.

Comment: У вас какая ОС? Пробовали это  https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/multiprocessing.html#cuda-in-multiprocessing.

Comment: @СергейКох мне нужно кроссплатформенное решение. Не проверял, так как cuda это не главная задача, у меня проект по распознованию объектов.

Comment: Пока не точно, ведь сначало проверял на виндовс в виртуалбокс но там я указывал девай cpu и было все ок, но на линуксе, на основной ос, начались проблемы. Вся загвоздка я так понял с gpu, хотя на линуксе и с cpu дальше код не работает, если мультипроцесс делать из ткинтера. Как эту проблему решить, вообще не понимаю, перепробовал разные варианты.

Comment: @insolor обновил тему, может что подскажите.

Comment: "Если во втором скрипте есть ткинтер окно, то скрипт работает ровно до его создания, на этом этапе поток тупо зависает (там окно не через mainloop, а просто update)" - в одном приложении должно быть только одно окно Tk, и только один mainloop. Дочерние окна должны создаваться как Toplevel, и mainloop (или его аналог) для них не нужен.

Comment: @insolor я во втором скрипте и использую toplevel, но не помогло

Comment: Ну вы пишите про какой-то update вместо mainloop - я не знаю, что за код там у вас, предполагаю что цикл типа while True с update внутри - такого делать не нужно. В принципе без кода это уже больше гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: @insolor на удивдение без TopLevel, а именно квк главное окно все заработало. В новых потоках и процессах должно же быть заново создабщееся окно а не дрчернее, мой профан

Comment: В новых потоках и процессах не должны создаваться окна.

Comment: Ну у меня почему-то только так заработало